# git update-index --assume-unchanged not working

Tags: git, github

I'm currently migrating a pre-existing huge java workspace to Git.
I created a git repo and trying work on it.
But git commands are way too slow, specially ***git-status*** , it takes around 3-5 second.

My workspace contains large files such as jars, gifs, xsds, xmls etc.
I ignored files as much as i can, but still its very slow.

So after some reading of Git docs, I found out about ***git update-index assume-unchanged*** and how does it work.

I applied it on around 80% of workspace projects by using following command:

***git ls-files -z folder/ | xargs -0 git update-index --assume-unchanged***
and got no error.

But even after that, if i execute ***git status***, it still take time.

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMz2B.png) to see git status time

Below I am attaching git configuration:

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dO38.png) to see git my git configuration

I even tried ***git update-index skip-worktree***
which also seems not to working.

I have windows 7 installed,8GB RAM, git version 2.17.0.windows.1
Total no. of files in workspace 35771

Please help me with this.

Comment: Pretty sure that with `35771` files, it has to check for commits on the server for each one of them.  This is a LOT of files.  Especially when many of them are probably quite large.  With `35771` files, if you have only added `1/2` of the files there are still 17880 files that it needs to check.  I would recommend `git add *`, `git commit 'Code!'` and then `git push` to flush out all of the changes and speed git up.

Comment: I know, working with 35771 tracked file is very slow, thats why I 
did **git update-index assume-unchanged** on 80% of my workspace, so it should be pretty fast by now. But it is'nt.